# Establishing SSH connection on a local machine to a system running within VirtualBox

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, debian, terminal

I'm running Debian on a Virtual box on Mac OS X. On the same machine, I would like to connect to Debian from the [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) terminal. *Simply put, I want to execute commands by Mac terminal not by writing them in Debian shell.* I tried running code:

```
ssh userName@10.0.2.15
```

As this is the **[ip](/questions/tagged/ip)** address that I got from running the:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig -a
```

command on Debian console. The command, however, returns error:

> `ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: It's not clear which machine is the host, a different client, the VM...  You should therefore clarify what each is with their IP and tell us what machine can bing which other ones.

Comment: Based on the 10.0.2.15 address, you have virtualbox configured to connect the VM to a NAT network. that means you would have to port forward Tcp/22 through the NAT. The much easier route is to set the VM to use bridged networking, and assign it an IP address on your LAN. then it will appear like just another computer on your network. http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

Comment: @JuliePelletier  There is only one machine. On the same Mac, I want to run two things: 1) VirtualBox with a Debian instance running, 2) Terminal/iTerm console with the *ssh* session connected to the Debian instance. In a word, the ssh connection is *within* one machine between OS inside VB and the system on which VB runs.

Comment: The information provided does not allow us to assume that it is not bridged, so it would be good to clarify that part, and also, as I previously asked, tell us which IP can ping which other IP.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks very much, it sounds like answer to me. I'll try to bridge it.